# How to find $f_{p}$ such that $\sum a_{i} x_{i} = 1 \implies \sum f_{p} (a_{i}) (x_{i})^{p} = 1 $?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, nonlinear-system

Suppose we have the equation $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_{i} x_{i} = 1 $$ for some coefficients $(a_{i})_{i=0}^{\infty} $. I wonder how to find corresponding $f_{p}(\cdot)$ such that  $$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} f_{p} (a_{i}) (x_{i})^{p} = 1 $$ when $p \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2} $.
Are there any results on this? Perhaps from the ([non](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_algebra))linear algebra, complex analysis or some other area?

Comment: can you clarify which ones are parameters and which ones variables?

Comment: @Quimey The $(a_{i})$ are parameters/coefficients, and the $x_{i}$ are variables.

Comment: If all the $x_i$ are variables, how can the first equation hold? maybe I'm misunderstanding this.

Comment: @Quimey Maybe I'm not explaining it well. We have, for instance, the equation $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {n+k+1 \choose k+1}\{ \zeta(n+k+2) - 1 \} = 1$ that is valid for all $n \geq 1$, where $\zeta(\cdot)$ is the Riemann zeta function. I consider  $x_{k} =  \zeta(n+k+2) - 1$ the variables here, but maybe my terminology is wrong or idiosyncratic.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, for example you could have all $a_i=1$, so $\sum x_i=1$ and for some $p$, $\sum x_i^p = 0$.

Comment: @Quimey In that case, one would have to find some $f_{p}(\cdot)$ such that $\sum f_{p}(1) x_{i}^{p} = 1 $. In principle, that could be possible, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115387/discussion-between-quimey-and-max-muller).

Comment: I don't think they will exist. For instance, if $a_k=1$ for $k\le n$ and $a_k=0$ for $k>n$, then the polynomials $\sum_{k=0}^n x_k^p$ (for $p=1,\cdots,n+1$) are algebraically independent.